# Create cron job or schedule jobs using calendar

Tags: shell-script, cron, php

On my project, I need to run my script at a specific time.

**My script:**

```
1.stop_instance_001.sh
2.change_instance001_m5.2xlarge.sh 
3.start_instance_001.sh
```

**Example:** I use fullcalendar web app to schedule my events.

6 november 2020

```
| Event |   Time  |              Script             |
| ----- | ------- | ------------------------------- |
|event1 |  20:00  | stop_instance_001               |
|event2 |  20:05  | change_instance001_m5.2xlarge   |
|event3 |  20:07  | start_instance_001              |
```

1. select the day you want to run the script.
2. select script from dropdown list.
3. select time to run script.
4. save!

After design my calendar, I don't know how to use PHP to convert these events to crontab. T_T

**crontab:**

```
00 20 * * * /home/ubuntu/stop_instance_001.sh
05 20 * * * /home/ubuntu/change_instance001_m5.2xlarge.sh 
07 20 * * * /home/ubuntu/start_instance_001.sh
```

Please find me the solution, Thanks..

Comment: Editing those changes into a crontab automatically is reasonably simple. But those insertion edits would be cumulative. The hard problem is to reliably remove any previous versions of the events. Typically, you would precede each created entry by a comment that unambiguously identified previous such events. Does it *have* to be PHP?

Comment: Yes you right, not have to PHP.
I think about shell script without cron, what do you think?

Comment: Key question is "how can we get the data out of FullCalendar". The site front page says there is an API, but it is not clear how you can interface with that, or from what languages (seems the product is web-based and written in JavaScript). Two of the features that look useful in this area are chargeable additional plugins (Scheduler Premium and Scheduler OEM).

Comment: Thanks Paul !, you saved my life.